# How to run nodejs on Linux Azure App Service? Getting 'cannot find module' error

Tags: node.js, linux, azure

Everything works great locally on my Windows PC, I even had this all running fine for a few months on the exact same Linux App Service. My local environment is running the same version of node and npm.

When I do a deploy from VS, I then SSH and type:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash 
apt-get install -y nodejs
npm install canvas | npm install fabric
```

That was all I had to do, however now I get the error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvocationException: Cannot find module 'fabric' Require stack:
>
> - Error: Cannot find module 'fabric' Require stack:
> - at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15) at Function.Module._load
>   (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27) at Module.require
>   (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) at require
>   (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18) at module.exports
>   (anonymous:4:40) at Server. ([eval]:1:2404) at
>   Generator.next () at [eval]:1:355 at new Promise
>   () at o ([eval]:1:100)

I've tried cleaning npm cache, deleting all files and re-publishing, npm install, npm update, with and without -g etc.

Any tips on how to fix this error? Also, preferably there is a better way so that I don't even need to SSH after every publish and manually type those 3 lines...

Thanks!

Comment: Probably this is because of Python: ```npm config set python python2.7```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I typed 'python' and it says:
Python 2.7.16 [GCC 8.3.0]